# passing and displaying array of objects in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have two input boxes which will take input from users and on click of a button will save the input in an array and display it on the screen.

The react code that I have written for the same is like this:

```
class Todo extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      input:[],
      desc:'',
      expense:'',
      list:[]
    }
    this.save=this.save.bind(this);
    this.changeDesc=this.changeDesc.bind(this);
    this.changeExpense=this.changeExpense.bind(this);
  }
  changeDesc(e){
    this.setState({
      desc:e.target.value
    })
  }
  
  changeExpense(e){
   this.setState({
      expense:e.target.value
     })
  }
  save(saveText){
    var list=this.state.list;
    list.push({
      text:saveText,    
    })
    this.setState({
      list:list,
      desc:'',
      expense:''
    })
    //console.log(input);
  }
  render(){
         return(
           <div>
           <Save saveText={this.save} text={this.state.input}/>
           <Display list={this.state.list}/>
             </div>
          )
  }
}
class Save extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      input:this.props.text
    }
    this.save=this.save.bind(this);
  }
  save(){
    var input=this.state.input;
    var desc=document.getElementById("desc").value;
    var expense=document.getElementById("expense").value;
    input.push(desc,expense);
    this.props.saveText(input);
    console.log(this.props.saveText);
    this.setState({
      input:[]
    })
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input type='text' id="desc" onChange={this.changeDesc}/>
        <input type="text" id="expense" onChange={this.changeExpense}/>
        <input type="button" value="save" onClick={this.save}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Display extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      todos:[]
    }
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
      todos:nextProps.list
    })
  }
  render(){
    var renderList=this.state.todos;
    var listElements=[];
    for(var i=0;i<renderList.length;i++){
    listElements.push(renderList[i]);
    console.log(listElements);
    }
    return(
      <div>{listElements}</div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

But this code is not displaying anything on the screen and I am getting errors like this for some given input.[image: Error]

The Codepen link for the same is: [Link](https://codepen.io/asinha/pen/yXrEYv?editors=0010)

What is wrong with the  react code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list contains an array of object text which iteself is an array of string,

Also you can simply map over it instead of having a for loop

```
render(){


    return(
      <div>{this.state.todos.map((item) => (<div>{item.text[0] + ' ' + item.text[1]}</div>))}</div>
    )
  }
```

**[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgGaeq?editors=0010)**

Comment: If I am mapping over it and I do item.desc and item.expense, then why does it through an error because eventually the todos[] has two objects desc and expense!

Comment: No your todos doesnt have objects with desc and expense but one object textthat is an array

Comment: Check the New codepen where I have modified your logic, to have desc and expense as an object : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzXyWR?editors=0010  and you dont have minified error here

Comment: can you refer to my codepen link again. How can I pass the same data through another component. I am getting the same errors minify error again and again

Comment: In your case, from your Display component you have returned `{listItems}`, where React feels that you may have returned an undefined item so just wrap it within divs like `<div>{listItems}</div>`  And I have edited your codepen only and made some changes which you can go through

Comment: Glad I could help :)